# Calculating value of the fourier series

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

In the following fourier series, how the red marked numbers are calculated?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to verify this equality is to work from the right hand side. Expand it into a Fourier series, and check that the result is the series on the left.  Then appeal to an appropriate theorem on the pointwise convergence of Fourier series; [Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions) is tailor-made for this case.

But if you insist on working from left to right, then complex analysis can help. The function $\sin (2k-1)x$ is secretly the imaginary part of $\exp((2k-1) i x)=z^{2k-1}$ where $z=\exp(ix)$. Then use the Taylor series
$$2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2k-1}}{2k-1} = \log\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$ 
but watch out: our $z$ is right on the border of the disk of convergence. Finally, use the fact that the map $w= \frac{1+z}{1-z}$ sends the unit disk onto the right half-plane, and the imaginary part of $\log$ picks up the argument of $w$. Said argument is $\pm \pi/2$ when $w$ is on the boundary of the right half-plane...

The last, but not the least: try to [type formulas](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting images. It's not that hard.